# How to repair a failed install?

Tags: software-center

I had to do a hard reboot on my computer while installing mysql-admin and now I get an error when trying to install it.

Here is the error message:
[image]

How can I "repair this" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I launched "synaptic" which told me how to fix it.

> sudo dpkg --configure -a